# Is it possible to have an 'IF' conditional statement nested within a 'CASE' conditional statement? (pseudocode)

Tags: pseudocode

I'm designing a pseudocode version of a programme thingy I made, in which one of the sections is someone inputting a number to select an option. When someone inputs a number, a value from a list is output. I thought using an 'IF' statement nested within a 'CASE' statement would make that task run more efficiently, but I'm not sure if that would still conform to the acceptable 'CASE' statement format. This is what I was envisioning for the first option:

```
**
CASE category OF
 '1' : PRINT "Members who have chosen to work as volunteers,"
  IF MemberInfo[2] = 'yes'
   PRINT "MemberInfo[0], MemberInfo[1]" 
**
```

The following numbers in the main 'CASE' statement would then follow the same format. Is this okay, or should I just make various 'IF' statements?

Answer (score 0):

It does not makes to use CASE here as we use CASE when there are multiple options to choose from. Given its just one condition and action based on that an 'if' is more appropriate.

An if nested within CASE is not a good programming structure. Go with either CASE or IF.

```
Input a number as category
If category is a number
then 
print list
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that makes sense. Real code can do it, so why not pseudocode?

(But if the other cases have the same format, there's probably a better way to do it: maybe a map lookup or using the category more dynamically, depending on what's changing between each case statement, and what stays the same.)